# UIWebView mobile site width

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, uiwebview

I am making an app which has a UIWebView, in which I need to display the mobile version of an SE question, However, the page seems to have a minimum width - 768 to be precise - which just happens to be the width of the tablet itself.

This is the code I am using:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312584/inject-a-local-javascript-into-uiwebview"]]];
}
```

Nothing fancy. My web view, however, has a width just a little smaller, which means that there is just a little bit of ugly side-scrolling involved.

How do I make the mobile site ignore that I'm on an iPad (it works fine on an iPhone), and just scale to whatever size I make the UIWebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It knows what you are by the User Agent, which you can see how to do in this question

[Change User Agent in UIWebView (iPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk)

Alternatively, you could inject JavaScript into the page after it loads and change the width of the body or main div

[Injecting JavaScript into UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786690/injecting-javascript-into-uiwebview)

To set the body width, see this question

[set body width in px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769385/set-body-width-in-px)